# Aligning Nested DIVs

Tags: html, layout

I am trying to have a group of DIVs within a webpage, and I cannot seem to get the layout like I want.  What I want is this... (no borders needed)

[image]

Here is my code...

```
<div id='participation_All'  style="height:100%">
    <div id='participation_Left' style="width: 100%; min-height: 600px"> 

    <div id='part_bargauge' style='float: left; width: 70%'></div>     
    <div id='part_listbox'></div>

   </div>
<div id='participation_Right' style="width: 100%; min-height: 600px"> 
    </div>

</div>
```

The problem is the part_Listbox is NOT showing up where I need it.  Instead, it is showing up on the left of the screen, below part_All.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try either flex or css table layout, flex is prefered.

Comment: Also, questions like this highly benefit from code snips. **DO NOT** screenshot your code as nobody is going to take the time to re-type it all.

Comment: *my source code was truncated* If you clicked on "code sample" first ad then pasted in the code then it only indented the first line. Paste in your code, select all of it, then click the "code sample" icon. Alternatively, since this is an HTML/CSS question, you can also paste your code into a runnable snippet (it's the icon after the image icon; the paper with angle brackets).

Comment: @@BSMP - Thanks.  I edited the question using the code snippets instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a framework like bootstrap, as already suggested. If you want to do it without you can edit the code below for your needs:

```
<div class='main' style='display:block; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:green;'>
    <div class='left' style='margin:10px;width:50%; height:90%; background-color:yellow; float:left;'>
        <div class='inner_left' style='margin:10px;width:40%; height:90%; background-color:purple; float: left;'></div>
        <div class='inner_right>' style='margin:10px;width:40%; height:90%; background-color:grey; float: right;'></div>
        <div class='clear' style='clear: both;'></div>
    </div>   
    <div class='right' style='margin:10px;width:30%; height:90%; background-color:blue; float:right;'>
    </div>
    <div class='clear' style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>
```

I would at least skip the inline css and move it to a css file which will be included in your finale page cause this kind of code is very very poor for maintenance. (but your choise in the end ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use Bootstrap row and column method

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">Left side  Content goes here</div><div class="col-md-4"> Right Side Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the style "float: left" to part_Listbox as well.

Here is a code pen with your layout and colors that you can play with.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONYOxL?editors=1010

```
<div id='part_all' style="height:500px; background-color:gray">
<div id='part_left' style='width:45%; height: 300px; margin:2%; background-   color:orange; float:left'>
    <div id='part_Bargauge' style='margin:2%; color:white; float: left; height: 80%; width: 70%; background-color:green;'>part_Bargauge</div>
    <div id='part_Listbox' style="margin:2%;color:white; float:left; height:80%; width: 20%; background-color:purple;">part_Listbox</div>
</div>
<div id='part_Right' style='color:white; float: left; width: 45%; min-height:300px; background-color: blue; margin: 2%;'>part_Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Float elements are basically 'aware' of each other and will function how you expect them to. But an element will default to position relative and basically fall below the floaters.

Try out using the flex styling too. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp